# Docker Compose Scan Wifi of Host Network

Tags: docker, networking, docker-compose

I have three containers:

- gui: frontend (communicates with core)
- core: backend (communicates with gui and mongo)
- mongo: database (communicates with core)

The application is an IOT app, and I want to scan the available wifi networks from my core container.

```
version: "3"
services:
    watchtower:
        container_name: watchtower
        image: talmai/rpi-watchtower
        env_file:
            - watchtower.env
        volumes:
            - /run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
    mongo:
        ports:
            - "27017:27017"
            - "27018:27018"
        container_name: mongo
        volumes:
            - ".tmp/mongo/data:/data/db"
            - ".tmp/backup:/data/backup"
        image: iotapp/iotapp_mongo:latest
        networks:
            - backend
    iotapp_gui:
        ports:
            - "80:80"
        container_name: iotapp_gui
        depends_on:
            - "iotapp_core"
        image: iotapp/iotapp_gui:latest
        networks:
            - frontend
    iotapp_core:
        ports:
            - "3000:3000"
        env_file:
            - core.env
        container_name: iotapp_core
        depends_on:
            - "mongo"
        privileged: true
        volumes:
            - ".tmp/logs:/data/logs"
            - ".tmp/backup:/data/backup"
            - "/etc/wpa_supplicant:/etc/wpa_supplicant"
            - "/etc/default/hostapd:/etc/default/hostapd"
        image: iotapp/iotapp_core:latest
        networks:
            - backend
            - frontend
        network_mode: host

networks:
    backend:
        driver: bridge
    frontend:
        driver: bridge
```

My problem is to make the host network available to the core container. I tried so far

- working with link and defining a network => cannot be used together
- defining a network with `driver: host` => only one instance of "host" network is allowed
- using `networks`, and `network_mode: host` on the `core` container => `'network_mode' and 'networks' cannot be combined`
- just using `network_mode: host` on core => `mongo` is not reachable anymore

Question:

How to make the network available but still let core communicate with the other containers?

Answer (score 0):

I use Linux named pipes to communicate between my host and my container. The host creates a named pipe on boot which has a loop to query the wifi SSIDs. The folder of the pipe is shared with the docker container. The docker container then queries the pipe:

wifi.pipe (runs at boot in the background):

```
#!/bin/bash
pipePath="/home/pi/app/pipes/wifi.pipe"
if [[ ! -p $pipePath ]]; then
  mkfifo $pipePath
fi

while true; do iwlist wlan0 scan | grep ESSID > $pipePath; done
```

Inside the docker container:

```
cat < /pipes/wifi.pipe
```

Docker compose:

```
...
volumes:
    - "/home/pi/app/pipes:/pipes"
...
```